# Evaluating multiple rspec expectations with cucumber

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, rspec-expectations

I am using rspec expectations with cucumber.
It seems that when using multiple expects in a cucumber steps, cucumber evaluates them until first of them fails.
However I want to continue running also other expects to get a clear picture of what went wrong. Can I somehow achieve this?

Example:
-let's suppose that response = "1", code = "2" and status = "3"

```
expect(response).to eq("0")
expect(code).to eq("2")
expect(status).to eq("1")
```

Cucumber will fail when evaluating response variable. But I want to check value of other two variables and get output for wrong status value too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would be:

```
expect({
  response: response,
  code: code,
  status: status}
).to eq({ response: "0", code: "2", status: "1" })
```

If the test fails, you would see two hashes comparead, with a diff clearly visible.

Comment: You actually answered my question. I am however interested if there exists any other solutions, because inside one of my step I call other steps. And if one of this called steps fails, execution immediately stops. But I don't want that.

Comment: @Tians i think a more cleaner way would be to make a custom rspec matcher, which takes the request as an argument, and then tests the status and the response. You can find some examples here: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher

Comment: I didn't know this was a problem, but I like it.

Comment: @tians, don't call steps inside other steps, its a really bad idea. Instead extract a helper method, and call that.